# Difference between foo() and function() { foo(); }

Tags: javascript

Is there any advantage of wrapping a function with an anonymous function?
I mean a particular example:

```
function asyncFuntion(callback) {
    setTimeout(callback, 6000);
};

asyncFuntion(function() {
    console.log('Calling after 6 s.');
});
```

and with the wrapped function:

```
function asyncFuntion(callback) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        callback();
    }, 6000);
};

asyncFuntion(function() {
    console.log('Calling after 6 s.');
});
```

In both cases output is the same. So is there any difference?
The second version is what I found learning js.
I realize that such a form is useful when we need closures but here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The second form allows you to pass arguments to `callback`, whereas the first form doesn't.

```
// 1st form
setTimeout(callback("This doesn't work as you might expect"), 6000);

// 2nd form
setTimeout(function() {
    callback("This works");
}, 6000);
```

If you're not passing arguments, then there is no advantage in wrapping the function whatsoever.

---

To be more thorough, [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) can help us with the first form:

```
setTimeout(callback.bind(this, "This works fine too"), 6000); 

// Even with Richard JP Le Guen's example by specifying the thisObj
setTimeout(customObj.alert.bind(customObj), 6000);
```

However, you will need to provide this method to browsers that don't support the event (namely Opera, Safari and IE 8, 7, 6).  The code to shim the method is available on the MDN documentation page.

Comment: `setTimeout(callback.bind(this, 'This works aswell'), 6000);`

Comment: @jAndy: yup, but not in older browsers without a shim.  Thank you for not suggesting `setTimeout(callback, 6000, 'This works as well')`, though ;)

Comment: @AndyE what do you mean it doesn't work in older browsers? they don't have `apply` in `Function.prototype` ?

Comment: @AndyE: lmao, didn't even know that setTimeout curry's the arguments to the callback function. I guess its not standard if you comment it like you did ?

Comment: @Esailija: `apply` is not sufficient for that purpose. We don't want the callback to immediately execute, but we want to bind the context and arguments for a call at some later point. So `bind()` is rather new.

Comment: @jAndy: yeah, it's non-standard.  IE accepts a different third argument - the scripting language to eval the code with (in the case of a string 1st argument).

Comment: @jAndy I know that apply is not the same, what I meant is that if the older browsers have apply, creating a bind method is so trivial that I wouldn't call it "without a shim" :P.

Comment: @Esailija: using `apply` is exactly how the method is shimmed.

Comment: I don't get it, `bind` (not the conveniently included method in modern browsers, but the functionality) is as old as `apply` or `call`  - there is no magic happening in the modern browser `bind` method. It simply returns a new function that has the old function and context in a closure. `call` and `apply` are the only native methods needed here. It's possible I am misunderstanding something though :)

Comment: @Esailija: `bind` in ECMAScript 5th does work slightly different, but not for this use case.  The point is that writing a method to do the work of `bind` (creating a function to run another in a specific context) in older browsers is what's known as a "shim" - a compatibility layer of code.  In my comments and answer, I was indicating that the code may not work without a shim, because `bind` doesn't exist in all current, in-use browsers.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't aware that "shim" is a programming term, I thought it was synonym for hack or something. Anyway, only the most bizarre use cases would require the native `bind` method instead of `jQuery.proxy` or quickly self made `Function.prototype.bind`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4392/discussion-between-andy-e-and-esailija)

Answer (score 5):

Wrapping a function in an anonymous function can avoid complications with the `this` keyword. ([read about them on quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html))

For example:

```
function CustomObject() {
    this.msg = "Hello world from my custom object";
    this.alert = function() {
        alert(this.msg);
    };
}

var customObj = new CustomObject();

setTimeout(customObj.alert, 1000); // the alert message says `undefined`
setTimeout(function() {
    customObj.alert();
}, 2000); // the alert message says "Hello world from my custom object"
```

Wrapping a function in an anonymous function is also key to using [closures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29) in JavaScript:

```
var arr = ['a','b','c','d','e'];

// will always alert undefined
for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(arr[i]);
    }, 1000*i);
}

// outputs the values of `arr`
for(var j=0; j<arr.length; j++) {
    setTimeout((function(indx) {
        return function() {
            console.log(arr[indx]);
        }
    }(j)), 1000*j);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Wrapping is useful if you need to have separate identity.

```
var x = function () { cleanup(); };
var y = function () { cleanup(); };
if (x === y) ... // not true
```

For example, some functions like `addEventListener` operate on identity.

```
element.addEventListener("myEvent", beep, false);
element.addEventListener("myEvent", beep, false);
```

The second time you call `addEventListener`, it says "I've already got a `beep`; I don't need to add another." When the `myEvent` event is fired, you get only one beep. If you want two beeps, you need to make sure the callbacks are different.

```
element.addEventListener("myEvent", function() { beep(); }, false);
element.addEventListener("myEvent", function() { beep(); }, false);
```

Each anonymous function is different, so this time you registered two functions (which happen to do the same thing). Now it will beep twice.

Comment: +1, this is one of those edge cases that most don't think about.  FWIW, this is another scenario where `Function.prototype.bind()` can be useful.